# Doclava show private methods in docs

Tags: android, javadoc, private

i am using doclava to generate docs for my Android project.
i want the docs to show every single variable, member and method. The documentation of doclava states that you should pass the -hidden flag or -private flag to generate documentation for the private members and methods.

I am using the following ANT build for my doclava

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="doc" name="api docs">
<target name="doc" description="my docs">
    <javadoc destdir="./" verbose="on" 

        classpath="/Users/johndoe/android-sdks/platforms/android-16/android.jar;"
        sourcepath="../gen;../src"
        maxmemory="512m"

        docletpath="doclava.jar"
        >
        <doclet name="com.google.doclava.Doclava" >
        <param name="-stubs" value="build/stubs" />

        <param name="-hdf"/> <param name="project.name"/> <param name=" "/>
        <param name="-templatedir" /> <param name="template" />
        <param name="-private" />
        <param name="-generatesources" />
        <!-- versioning -->
         <param name="-since"/> <param name="./previous.xml"/> <param name="v1" />
        <param name="-apiversion" value="v2"/>
        <!-- federation -->
        <param name="-federate" /><param name="JDK"/>
        <param name="http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?"/>
        <param name="-federationxml"/><param name="JDK"/>
        <param name="http://doclava.googlecode.com/svn/static/api/openjdk-6.xml"/>

       <param name="-federate" /><param name="android"/>
        <param name="http://d.android.com/reference"/>
        <param name="-federationxml"/><param name="android"/>
        <param name="http://doclava.googlecode.com/svn/static/api/android-8.xml"/> 


        </doclet>
    </javadoc>
</target>
</project>
```

But still doclava will only generate the methods and members that are stated public.

any thoughts what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

add `access="private"` under your `<javadoc />` tag